# Qual a Diferença entre os CharSet : DOS850 x ISO8859_1 x WIN1252?

Tags: banco-de-dados, codificação-de-caracteres

Qual a diferença entre esses *Character Sets*: `DOS850` x `ISO8859_1` x `WIN1252` pois vejo isso na hora de criar um banco de dados e não entendo direito qual as suas diferenças? Sei que tem relação à língua portuguesa mais é só isso que sei...

Comment: Variações do mesmo conjunto de Caracteres....

Comment: Extensão do US-ASCII usando "vi na resposta abaixo" kkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o Site

- **ISO 8859-1** : Idiomas ocidentais e ocidentais europeus (*inglês, alemão, francês, espanhol, português, etc.*) 
  Como esses idiomas são usados ​​em grandes partes do mundo (*Europa, Américas, Austrália, África*), esses são os conjuntos de caracteres mais amplamente usados. 
  **Windows 1252** ou **Win1252** e **ISO 8895-1** são praticamente iguais na faixa de 160,255. **ISO 8859-1** e o **Win1252** é uma extensão do US-ASCII usando o oitavo bit.
- **DOS850** - Foi subistituido pelo **Win1252** esse conjunto possui menos caracteres que os outros 2.

### Veja Abaixo as tabelas com as diferenças de cada CharSet

- **DOS850** Tabla de caracteres
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **ISO 8895-1** Tabla de caracteres
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **WIN 1252** Tabla de caracteres
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom saber agora posso escolher o que melhor serve para minha aplicação!